# How to retrieve data from json-server

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm facing an issue in my React application. I want to print the **userData** from **my db.json** file to the console when a **button** is clicked in the **Data component**. However, I'm encountering errors in my **<App.tsx>** component.

```
//Error
//App.tsx

ERROR in src/App.tsx:31:8
TS2786: 'Data' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element.
    29 |   return (
    30 |     <div className="App">
  > 31 |       <Data />
       |        ^^^^
    32 |     </div>
    33 |   );
    34 | }
```

I don't know what I have done wrong. I request you to point out the mistake I have made to do this to me.

```
//App.js

import Data from "./Components/http";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Data />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
//db.jason

{
  "userData": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Gibson",
      "age": "21"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Joseph",
      "age": "12"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
import axios from "axios";

export function getUser() {
  return axios
    .get("http://localhost:3006/userData")
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })

    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

```
//Data.tsx
import { getUser } from "../Api/api";

export default function Data() {
  function displayuser() {
    getUser();

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={displayuser}>get</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just fyi, it's `json` not `jason` (it's short for `javascript object notation`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem in parentheses. Try this:

```
export default function Data() {
    function displayuser() {
        getUser()
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={displayuser}>get</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This is correct. Thanks, Vladislav.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is "data cannot be used as a jsx element". You are trying to use a component in your jsx (after your return).
So instead of doing something like this:

```
return (
  <div className="app">
    <data />
  </div>
)
```

You should put it inside curly brackets like this:

```
return (
  <div className="app">
    {<data />}
  </div>
)
```

Whenever you are using some function, variable or whatever that is not plain jsx, you need to put it inside curly brackets.